# Access property value based on array of properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have an object

```
const someObject = {
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: {
        abc: [
            'def',
            'ghi'
        ]
    }
}
```

And a dynamically generated array with a path to the value needed

```
const someArray = ['baz', 'abc', 1]
```

How can I access the object value based on array values?

In the example it would return `'ghi'`

Comment: const s = someArray;

someObject[s[1]][s[2]][s3]

Answer (score 1):

You could do that dynamically, using [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) to take a copy from `someObject` and loop over array of keys `someArray` each iteration update `cloneSomeObject` with new value of that object:

```js
const someObject = {
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: {
        abc: [
            'def',
            'ghi'
        ]
    }
}
const someArray = ['baz', 'abc', 1];
let cloneSomeObject = structuredClone(someObject);
for(let key of someArray){
 cloneSomeObject = cloneSomeObject[key]
}
console.log(cloneSomeObject);//ghi
```